# calling ioctl() from Java - how is it done?

Tags: android

I need to access a serial port from within my app (the app has read/write permission to the device).
How do I make ioctl() calls from my Java-based app ?

Comment: I also found a good general JNI tutorial: http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html

Comment: You may want to look at PureJavaComm: http://www.sparetimelabs.com/purejavacomm/index.html It does a lot of the dirty work for you, Rick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JNI -- and it wont be easy

JNI is the Java Native Interface. It defines a way for managed code (written in the Java programming language) to interact with native code (written in C/C++). It's vendor-neutral, has support for loading code from dynamic shared libraries, and while cumbersome at times is reasonably efficient.

Comment: I found a good code sample: http://www.samsungmomentforum.com/samsung-moment-applications/help-getting-led-flash-to-work/15/?wap2

Comment: Most recent available archive of that link: http://web.archive.org/web/20100314115010/http://www.samsungmomentforum.com/samsung-moment-applications/help-getting-led-flash-to-work/15/