# Can Java directly open the device file node like C?

Tags: java, c, linux

As we know, the C can open the /dev file node by the Linux system API. Like this:

```
int fd = open("/dev/hello", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK);
```

So , is there any way to do this using JAVA without JNI ?

Thanks.

Comment: just use it as a regular file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since on Unix "everything is a file". You just open `/dev/hello` like you open your file `/home/jerikc/some.txt` ...

<sup>Perhaps your question is how to pass `O_NONBLOCK` to [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) syscall in Java....</sup>

Comment: is there any way to do the file_operations like ioctl using java ? Thanks.

Comment: This is a different question. You want to ask how to to do `ioctl` in Java. Google for it, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8163166/841108)