# Java simulate multiple keys press in console without X environment or service

Tags: java

Is it possible to simulate multiple keys press in Java application which is running in system without graphics environment or even started by `systemd`? It doesn't have to be multisystem solution, may just work in Linux.

If there is windows environment running I could use `Robot` as described here [How to simulate keyboard presses in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7746017/3626048) but in this case I can't (I get `AWTException: headless environment`)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There may be a better way than simulating keypresses.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I don't think there is better way, third party application is listening for keys pressed and running its own action then

Comment: If that third party program is running inside a tty, you could interface with ioctl via jni and send whatever you want. See [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-do-i-stuff-a-keystroke-into-another-virtual-terminal%27s-stdin-839110/) thread. The solution is in C, but it's a start.

Comment: Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163166/calling-ioctl-from-java-how-is-it-done) about ioctl + jni

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca thank you, I will try that

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca what if 3rd party app would be running inside graphical environment but my app would work as service (using systemd/systemctl)?